# ¿Cómo hago varias consultas a MySQL con PHP? (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, html5, mysqli

Tengo que traer información de una base de datos de los 1 o más Id's que sean enviados (depende los que sean seleccionados), pero el método que utilicé no parece ser eficiente, creía que había una función parecida a `store_result()` o algo así, no he tenido tiempo de revisar por la prepa. He ido verificando si los las sentencias de SQL se generan correctamente y si lo hacen, el problema (creo) esta en la lineas:
`$resultado = $conn->query(${"sql_$i"});` `$lente_compra=$resultado->fetch_assoc();`, imagino que es por las funciones utilizadas, pero no tengo mucha idea de cuales puedo utilizar. Si se necesita más información puedo brindarla.

```
if(isset($_POST['id_compra'])){
  $ids = $_POST['id_compra']; //esta variable es un array
  $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad']; //esto también es un array
  if (sizeof($ids) > 0) {
    for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($ids) ; $i++) {
      ${"id_$i"} = $ids[$i];
      ${"cantidad_$i"} = $cantidad[$i];
    }
    try {
      require_once('includes/funciones/connection_db.php');
      for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($ids) ; $i++) {
        $id_consulta =  ${"id_$i"}
        ${"sql_$i"} = "SELECT (nombre_lente, precio_lente) FROM lentes_normales WHERE id_lente = {$id_consulta}";
        $resultado = $conn->query(${"sql_$i"});
        $lente_compra = $resultado->fetch_assoc(); ?>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row"> <!-- esto de aquí era solo para ver si funcionaba bien, pero no funciona -->
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <h2><?php echo $lente_compra['nombre_lente']; ?></h2><!-- 'nombre_lente' y 'precio_lente' es el nombre de la columna en la base de datos ->
              <h2><?php echo $lente_compra['precio_lente']; ?></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn->close();
  }
}else{
  exit('Hubo un error, por favor regresa.');
}
```

Este es el pedazo de HTML que envía los datos de los ID's (esta parte del código se imprime en función de la cantidad de items agregados a un carro de compras)

```
<input type="number" class="id_item_compra d-none" name="id_compra[]" value="<?php echo $datos[$i]['Id']; ?>">
```

Consejos externos a la duda planteada son bienvenidos, soy algo nuevo en PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la sentencia "in" de mysql para hacer un implode de los id y buscarlos todos en una misma consulta, ya despues solo iteras sobre 1 resultado. Seria algo asi:

```
$sql = "SELECT (nombre_lente, precio_lente) FROM lentes_normales WHERE id_lente in (".implode(',', $ids).")";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
while ($lente_compra = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $lente_compra['nombre_lente'];// UTILIZAR ESTA VARIABLES PARA FORMAR TU CODIGO HTML
    $lente_compra['precio_lente'];
}
$conn->close();
```

> Fuente: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in
>   http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php

Comment: Creo que la linea de la consulta debería ser así `$sql = "SELECT (nombre_lente, precio_lente) FROM lentes_normales WHERE id_lente in (".implode(',', "$ids").")";`, solo le puse comillas a `$ids` para que se corte la cadena de texto ahí y tome en cuenta la variable. Igual gracias, veré si funciona.